# Acts as votable AJAX refesh button without refreshing page Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I'm trying to get my vote count to update the number of counts using javascript so the entire page doesnt reload. Currently it does this once, however you cannot click that button again without refreshing the page. How do I make it possible to click the like button to continously like and unlike the pin without refreshing the page?

pins_controller.rb:

```
def upvote
    @pin.upvote_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { count: @pin.get_upvotes.size } }
    end
end

def un_upvote
    @pin.unliked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { count: @pin.get_upvotes.size } }
    end
end
```

index.html.haml:

```
- if current_user.voted_for? pin
    = link_to unlike_pin_path(pin), method: :put, :remote => true, class: "btn btn-default vote", data: { type: :json } do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
            =pin.get_upvotes.size
- else
    = link_to like_pin_path(pin), method: :put, :remote => true, class: "btn btn-default vote", data: { type: :json } do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
            =pin.get_upvotes.size

:javascript 
 $('.vote')
 .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
 .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
 .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
 .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) {
 $(this).find("span").text(data.count);
});
```

Comment: You don't need a put method here, you just have to bind the click event to your ajax url.

Comment: I can't see your link :/

Comment: see if this helps: http://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails